# Wordpress adding a tag and changing the URL on load

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type "profile"
I need the same profile to load when requesting 3 differnt URLs, example:

- mysite.com/city1/bob
- mysite.com/city2/bob
- mysite.com/city3/bob

These should all load bob's profile.

I added the cities as categories and assigned bob to each category.

Now when I go to these links they all load bob's profile, but the URL changes on load. I want to stop the URL from changing.

Example:

- **mysite.com/city1/bob** loads the page, but becomes
  **mysite.com/city1/tag1/bob**
- **mysite.com/city3/bob** loads the page, but becomes
  **mysite.com/city1/tag1/bob**

I need it to stop adding the tag, and I need it to stop switching to city1.

How can I do this in wordpress?

The permalink is set as /%category%/%postname%

---

update, I am using a curl request in my 404 page to load the content for now as a hack:

```
$c = curl_init(get_site_url() . '/blog/people/'.$the_slug);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$html = curl_exec($c);
echo $html;
```

But I am sure this is not the best way to do it, I am trying to use add_action( 'template_redirect','myfunction') which is working to detect the url and load the post I want into a variable, but I can't seem to set the $post global to that post. It just ends up loading the homepage.

Is this possible: User requests URL that does not exist, I use a hook like template_redirect and render a page based on what they requested, and leave the URL as what they requested? Can I do this without curl?

Comment: I'm thinking of using the 404 page to check the url and load a post based on that and embed it in the 404 page.

Comment: Isn't there an option in the Wordpress settings to stop that happening? Could be wrong.

Comment: I don't think so. And core behaviour is for every page to have 1 permalink, and if a category is in the permalink it uses the category with the lowest ID.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this plugins, it'll solve the tag issue from the URL

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-tag-base/

Comment: I already have that installed, it did help with the URL although for one single person it still puts the tag in the url and I don't know why. The main thing is forcing wordpress to change the $page based on the url while maintaining the URL.

Comment: did you reset your existing files what you modified to get this solution.

Comment: Yes. I ended up resolving the tag issue by disabling the cache plugin. I still wish to find a solution to my problem without using cURL.

Comment: He is using custom post type as he mentioned so this plugin wouldn't work.

Comment: @nicholmikey please could you explain few more about the section of cURL actually what you want to do.

Comment: I want to detect the url being requested and return a page based on the URL, while maintaining the URL the user typed in. I can put a post in several categories, but it will always change the url to a permalink using the category with the lowest ID. Example, you could type in mysite.com/bob/toasters/ and I want it to load mysite.com/bread/toasters, but while keeping the url they typed in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin, I hope it'll solve the tag issue

http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-taxonomy-base-slug/

Comment: I can see how that would help with the tag issue, but it ended up being a caching issue. The remaining issue is how to server a page while maintaining the URL the user typed in. So far I figured out how to do it with cURL, but I am looking for a method that does not use cURL.